# How to open a directory from intent in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file

I am trying to open a directory with the help of an intent to show the user what is the content inside that folder but I am unable to do so,
but I don't know why the folder won't open and I get this "Can't use this folder" on the file manager.

[image]

```
               open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/" + "XYZ";
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                openDirectory(uri);

            }
        });
```

The method

```
public void openDirectory(Uri uriToLoad){
        // Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
        int result = 1;

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

        // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
        // the system file picker when it loads.
        intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, uriToLoad);

        startActivityForResult(intent, result);
    }
```

I want to open the folder XYZ after clicking on the button

Comment: There is no XYZ folder visible in your picture. Browse to it first.

Comment: it is inside of Documents, I am showing  the result after clicking the button in that picture @blackapps

Comment: Well browse to the Documents directory first. Then to the XYZ directory and open it. It is pretty unclear where you are strugling with.

Comment: But the user won't know where actually  XYZ folder is, The whole purpose of that intent is to show the user where his files are getting stored which is inside XYZ folder

Comment: Then why dont you write that in your post?

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to open a directory with the help of an intent to show the user what is the content inside that folder

There is no standard `Intent` action for that, sorry. Your code is trying to let the user select a document tree.

It is also doing that incorrectly, as `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` does not take a `file://` `Uri` as a value. That needs to be some `Uri` that you obtained previously from the Storage Access Framework, such as via some past `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` request.

> I don't know why the folder won't open and I get this "Can't use this folder" on the file manager

From Android's standpoint, your `EXTRA_INITIAL_URI` value is little better than a random string.

> But the user won't know where actually XYZ folder is

Then perhaps you should have let the user choose the location in the first place, rather than forcing a particular location. For example, you could use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` to let the user decide where to place the document on the user's device (or the user's cloud storage, the user's network file server, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know using Intent you can browse, open and create files, that shared for all apps by the system. In this case for get file path to open, you can use next code like this (pardon for my Kotlin):

```
private var launcherForResult =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            result.data.also { uri -> filePath = uri.toString() }
        }
    }

private fun getFilePath() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT).apply {
        type = "*/*"
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    }
    launcherForResult.launch(intent)
}
```

As for the directory, it usually opens the last one that was opened before.

If you don't want other applications to see your files, store them in your application's private directory